# Using $u$-substitution for this particular problem

Tags: calculus, integration

In the solution attached, the substitution of $u = \tan(x)$ is used; why can't $u = \sec(x)$ be used? $u = \sec(x), du = \sec(x)\tan(x)$ gives an integral of $udu = \sec^2(x)\tan(x)$, but so does $u = \tan(x), du = \sec^2(x) udu = \sec(x)^2\tan(x)$, but clearly my thinking isn't correct since different substitutions arrive at different answers.[Here is the link below of the solution:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeNig.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please try to format with MathJax, it helps us help you.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular integral
$$\int \tan x \sec^2 x \ dx = \int \sec x (\sec x \tan x)\, dx$$
we can make two possible substitutions, namely $u=\tan x$ or $u=\sec x$. Considering only the LHS and the first substitution, yields
$$\int u du = \frac12 u^2+c=\frac12 \tan^2 x+c_1 \tag{1}$$
and considering now the RHS and the substitution $u=\sec x$, this yields
$$\int udu = \frac12 u^2+c=\frac12 \sec^2 x+c_2 \tag{2}$$
This functions are clearly unequal. This is where the integration constant becomes important, since if we have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f'=g'$ we can conclude from here that there exists some real number $c$ so that $f=g+c$.

Also see my other answer for this right [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273378/dont-the-derivatives-of-arctan-x-and-operatornamearccot-x-imply-theyre/3273384#3273384).

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: As a follow up: are both substitutions technically correct and only differ by a constant C? Is there a reason why the solution opted for the former substitution? I also checked the integral on symbolab and it used u = tan(x).

Comment: The first thing you said is correct. To your second question, I don't think there is a specific reason, only that the substitution $ u = \tan x $ is the most obvious in this case. Both answers can be presented without any problem.