# Integral of $(-1/(1 + x^2))$

Tags: integration

I had a doubt that the integral of $\frac{-1}{1+x^2}$ is given as negative tan inverse $x$. Isn't it equal to $\cot$ inverse ($x$) ?

Comment: Post your attempts.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Don't be discouraged by the downvotes, or the negative comments.  This seems to be to be a perfectly good question.  Research is shown since $\cot^{-1}x$ is an antiderivative.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3274051/413285

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 5):

The answers are completely equivalent:
$$
\int-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=-\arctan x+c
$$
but also
$$
\int-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx=\operatorname{arccot} x+c
$$
because the functions $-\arctan x$ and $\operatorname{arccot} x$ differ by a constant: indeed
$$
\operatorname{arccot} x+\arctan x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}
$$